# How to change TextView text inside recyclerView items without notifyItemChanged?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView which shows `a title and link preview` in every item. I want to search text in `title` and highlight `searched_text` if title contains the text.
Problem is: When I search something, everything works as expected but `link preview start again` and it takes few seconds to load preview again.
Is there any way to prevent reloading/restarting link preview? or
Is there any way to notify just a textView inside item and keep the other thing as it was?

Code for searching:

```
public boolean performSearch(TextView textViewResult,String searchKey){
    this.searchKey = searchKey;

    searchedPosition.clear();
    for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++){
        if(links.get(i).getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey)) {
            searchedPosition.add(i);
        }
    }

    if(searchedPosition.size()==0)
        return false;//for downArrow
    else {
        currentPosition = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<searchedPosition.size();i++)
            notifyItemChanged(searchedPosition.get(i));

        scrollListener.scrollToPosition(searchedPosition.get(currentPosition));

        return true;
    }
}
```

onBindViewholder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final FileLayoutHolder2 holder, final int position) {

    if(searchKey!=null && links.get(position).getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(searchKey)){
        String newString = links.get(position).getTitle().replaceAll(
                "(?i)"+ Pattern.quote(searchKey),
                "<font color='red'>"+searchKey+"</font>");
        holder.textViewHeading.setText(Html.fromHtml(newString));
    }
    else{
        holder.textViewHeading.setText(links.get(position).getTitle());
    }

    try {//code for showing link preview: asynctask
     }
    catch(Exception ignored){}
    
}
```

Comment: Use Diff Utill. prevents to update not changed items

Comment: There's a [variant of `notifyItemChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyitemchanged) which takes in a `payload` object. You can use that payload to differentiate between partial and full updates.

Comment: Thanks. Working as expected